# Is it possible to set a default selected value only after the dropdown is opened in MantineUI's Select component?

Tags: reactjs, mantine

I am using the Select component from MantineUI v6 in my project. By default, I want the select box to have no value selected. However, I want to set a default value ('Asia/Tokyo' in this case) only after the user clicks on the select box and the dropdown options are displayed.

In the following example, the default value is set to 'Asia/Tokyo' using the defaultValue prop. As a result, the value is set even before the user interacts with the select box. I would like to change this so that the default value is only selected after the dropdown is opened by the user.

```
<Select
  data={TIME_ZONE_OPTIONS}
  defaultValue={'Asia/Tokyo'}
  searchable
  value={form.values['timeZone'] ?? null}
  variant="default"
/>
```

Is it possible to achieve this behavior with MantineUI's Select component?

Comment: you could use `onDropdownOpen`? If value is `undefined` assign your default to what ever your backing object is. https://mantine.dev/core/select/?t=props

Comment: This [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-c9jmna?file=src%2FApp.tsx) should give you an idea of what I was talking about and point you in the right direction for creating what your want.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a "placeholder" value that you could set as well as "touched" (boolean) to know if a user has put focus on the dropdown or not at least once. These are basic variables in React forms, so I would imagine they would still work.

This is an example of a MantineUi Select dropdown with a placeholder:

```
<Select
mt="md"
comboboxProps={{ withinPortal: true }}
data={['React', 'Angular', 'Svelte', 'Vue']}
placeholder="Pick one"
label="Your favorite library/framework"
classNames={classes}
/>
```

I believe you would just have to add the 'placeholder' variable to yours and it should work